# Use ajax to show-hide only a subset of image

Tags: css, ajax

I got this idea, in a NO CMS site... i have about 50 images,, that cannot be display all at once. SO the idea, is to display the first 15, then click on next, hide those and display the next 15 etc etc

Hot to do that with ajax or wit php and css ?

count, add class hidden, and show ?

---

or another way to do that... in php or jQuery, how to get the first 15 element of a div with class"image" and add class : showimage, then on click NEXT button : remove all the class showimage, and show the image 16 to 30

---

code look like that :

```
<div id="gallery2"> <!-- Gallery de photos --> 

<a href="ia/new_01.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
<img src="timthumb.php?src=ia/new_01.jpg&amp;h=<?php echo $size ?>" title="Cliquer pour agrandir" 
alt="Pont Neuf - Ile de la Cité - Paris - France - Aquarelle <br> Conception personnelle"/></a>

<a href="ia/new_02.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
<img src="timthumb.php?src=ia/new_02.jpg&amp;h=<?php echo $size ?>" title="Cliquer pour agrandir" 
alt="Studebaker Hawk - Concept rétro <br> Conception personnelle"/></a>

<a href="ia/new_03.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
<img src="timthumb.php?src=ia/new_03.jpg&amp;h=<?php echo $size ?>" title="Cliquer pour agrandir" 
alt="Corvette - Concept rétro <br> Conception personnelle"/></a>

<a href="ia/new_04.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
<img src="timthumb.php?src=ia/new_04.jpg&amp;h=<?php echo $size ?>" title="Cliquer pour agrandir" 
alt="Thunderbird - Concept rétro <br> Conception personnelle"/></a>

<a href="ia/new_05.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
<img src="timthumb.php?src=ia/new_05.jpg&amp;h=<?php echo $size ?>" title="Cliquer pour agrandir" 
alt="Les autos de mon père <br> Conception personnelle"/></a>
```

and on and on and on.... for 50 images

Comment: If you have a ton of images, you could also lazy load them: https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload

Comment: good point, point i timthumb them... so no worry about bandwith

Comment: in jquery you can get $(this).length that get me let say 50 item, but to get item #7 a class, how to get it ?

Comment: By telling i need to filter it to "shiplu" i just got the idea to google jQuery filter, and it look interesting... maybe i will go thi way  : http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont neex ajax for this. You can put all the image urls in an JS array and when a then next button is clicked you just hide the current 15 images and add new 15 images from the array. You render them on the fly. So images will be rendered by browser on the fly.

```
var images=[]; // it'll contain images.
var ptr=0;
var length = 15;
function show(offset, count){
    for(var i=offset;i<offset+count;i++){
        // add image images[i] in the image container.
    }
}
function next(){
    // empty the image container
    ptr+=length
    show(ptr, length);
}

show(0, length); // initial call to display first chunk of images
```

Now for the next button you just add `next` function as click handler.

Comment: what if images are located on the server? Just changing the source won't help here

Comment: and i have a description field to show when click (just like highslide) so, i need to write definition for all of them... i just need a way to filter it in fact

Comment: if the images are on server he will have to dump all the urls in the first place. And it should be in an JS array.

Comment: take a look at the code, and see the array way is a redo, and i dont want to go there